# Android Studio Firebase matcher & adapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my code.I had tested that it can successfully to find the data that contained "456",but it can't add it into my adapter.How can I solve it ?

```
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren() ){
                    String find = ds.child("titles").getValue().toString();
                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*456.*");
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(find);
                    adapter.add(matcher.group());

            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
```

The wrong message is  : at

> com.example.user.ideal.List$2.onDataChange(List.java:86)
>    86 : adapter.add(matcher.group());

Answer (score 0):

most likely the data is added to the adapter fine, but the adapter doesn't realize it needs to update its view. To make it do so, call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after you're done:

```
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren() ){
                String find = ds.child("titles").getValue().toString();
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*456.*");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(find);
                adapter.add(matcher.group());
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
  }
```

Comment: I had add it , and it's still the same wrong message.

Comment: Ah, I had not seen the error message. Please edit your question to include the complete stack trace and exception message.